# Spring ExceptionHandler for Request method 'POST' not supported

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to customize the response when a caller uses wrong HTTP method.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/simulator/table/{id}/action", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public GenericResponse doSomething(HttpServletRequest servletRequest, @PathVariable("id") String id, @RequestBody MyRequest request)
        throws BadRequestException, AuthorizationFailedException {
    return response;
}
```

I am able to catch many error states like malformed JSON input

```
@ExceptionHandler({HttpMessageNotReadableException.class})
public ResponseEntity resolveException(HttpServletRequest request, HttpMessageNotReadableException e) {
    log.error("Error when parsing the request {}\n{}", request.getRequestURI(), "a", e);
    GenericResponse response = new GenericResponse("FAILED", error);
    return new ResponseEntity<Object>(response, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

Now I want to catch when a client uses POST instead of PUT

This generic catcher does not work:

```
@ExceptionHandler
public ResponseEntity resolveException(HttpServletRequest request, Exception e) {
    log.error("Error when parsing the request {}\n{}", request.getRequestURI(), "a", e);
    GenericResponse response = new GenericResponse("FAILED", error);
    return new ResponseEntity<Object>(response, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

How can I catch and override it?

Comment: Spring Boot already sends a correct error response (better than yours) if you use an incorrect HTTP method. Why do you want to redo what the framework already does?

Comment: I have defined JSON format for the response with some additional attributes.

Comment: Then do what the documentation says you should to to use your JSON attributes: define a bean of type ErrorAttributes: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-error-handling